# Issue with setting bSortable from a variable in datatables

Tags: javascript, sorting, datatables

I am trying to implement the hide sorting option for a particular columns by making use of datatables plugin in php.
If I write the following code then its working:
    "aoColumns" : [{'bSortable': false},null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,{'bSortable': false}],

But I need dynamic and that is why I use a variable and the value of that(for my case `{'bSortable': false},null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,{'bSortable': false}` I store it in a js variable called `excluded_clmns_sorting`). Even if I am trying to print the value of `excluded_clmns_sorting`, it's showing `{'bSortable': false},null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,{'bSortable': false}`. Then I coded like `"aoColumns" : [excluded_clmns_sorting],` but it is showing error in console.The error is "`TypeError:oCol is undefined`".
So please let me know where is the problem.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect your problem is that you are assigning a string to excluded_clmns_sorting.  But, it's hard to be sure with so little info.  If that is the case, you need to JSON.parse the string before passing it to datatables.  Datatables is expecting an array for aoColumns.

Either of these work:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var excluded_clmns_sorting = JSON.parse('[{"bSortable": false},  null, null,  null, {"bSortable" : false}]');
    //var excluded_clmns_sorting = [{"bSortable": false},  null, null,  null, {"bSortable" : false}];
    $('#example').dataTable({
        "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
        "aoColumns": excluded_clmns_sorting
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ave8q/